# Data Type/Length in Parameterized Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic, prepared-statement

I'm using Classic ASP/MySQL to insert a long user input in to my database, generated from a rich text editor. The column is set to LONG-TEXT.

Being new to parameterized queries (prepared statements), I am not sure of the data length to use for this particular query.

This is my 'Add Parameter' statement for a simple VARCHAR query:

```
Const ad_varChar = 200
Const ad_ParamInput = 1

Set newParameter = cmdConn.CreateParameter("@firstName", ad_varChar, ad_ParamInput, 50, firstName)
cmdConn.Parameters.Append newParameter
```

As you can see, I used the value 50 for the data length. What do I use for a long-text column, where the users data length is unknown? It could be 50, or it could be 8000!

Comment: Please stop using the "asp" tag.  It is redundant since you've already used the "asp-classic" tag, and the tag descriptions says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use length of itself?

```
Set newParameter = cmdConn.CreateParameter("@firstName", ad_varChar, ad_ParamInput, Len(firstName), firstName)
```

Comment: I did actually wonder that myself. I didn't use LENB as Kul-Tigin suggested, I used LEN. LENB is for bytes not character length

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Had to say Yikes! :) I'll update that, thanks.